# How to change cell value alignment in ipysheet sheet from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ipywidgets, python-interactive

how can i change the alignment of an entire column or an individual cell in ipysheet ?

I tried :

```
for k,c in enumerate(sheet1.cells):
    c.style['textAlign']='left'
```

but it doesnt work (might be deprecated).
I was expecting the values in the cells to be displayed with the text starting on the left-most side of the cell, but nothing changed.

Thank you !

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your post may attract more attention if you edit it to be executable (e.g. include all imports and define variables), share the output you get, and manually create the output you want (so there's no ambiguity).

Answer (score 0):

I actually answered my own question, you just have to add `c.send_state()` at the end of the for loop that i showed in the question.